# how to retrieve the values from database for onchange event of dropdown for multiple rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a button which keeps on adding the rows. In each row there is a dropdown control for activity and textbox for amount. Based on the value selected in the dropdown I need to retrieve the amount from database using jQuery ajax call. The dropdowns are added dynamically by clicking add button.

### Example:

In the 1st row I select an activity. I need the amount related to that activity in the 1st textbox.

Similarly, In the 2nd row I select an activity. I need the amount related to that activity in the 2nd textbox.

How can I do this with the help of either javascript or jQuery? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

### Code

```
var wpid = 2;
function addWPActivity() {
    var table = document.getElementById("wpTable");
    rowCountWPTable = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCountWPTable);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<select class = "form-control" id="SelectedWorkProgram' + wpid + '" onchange="OnWPChange(this)"><option>--Select Work Program--</option></select>';
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = '<select class = "form-control" id="SelectedActivity' + wpid + '" ><option>--Select Activity--</option></select>';
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="wpAmount' + wpid + '" onchange="GetTotalAmount()"/>';
    GetValues();
    wpid++;
}
```

### Ajax Call

```
    function OnActivitySelect(obj) {
    var block = $("#BlockSelect option:selected").text();

    var activ = obj.value;
    var ID = {
        id: activ
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBudgetByWPAID", "Payments")',
    data: ID,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {

            var budg = data;
           // $("wpAmount").val = data;
            document.getElementById("wpAmount").value = data;
        }
        //$("#wpAmount1").focusout(function () {
        //    var amou = document.getElementById("wpAmount1").value;
        //    var due = (amou - budg);
        //    document.getElementById("due1").value = due;
        //});
    }
});
```

}

### My Controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public double GetBudgetbywpaID(long id)
    {
        double wpabudget = function.GetBudgetByWPAID(id);

        return wpabudget;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new css class `myActivity` to your activity dropdown element so that we can use that as a jQuery selector later. Also set the wpid value in an HTML 5 data attribute to the table row. We need to also set a css class `myAmt` to the amount textbox for accessing it later.

Since you are using jQuery, you might use some jQuery shorthand methods to build your html table row. Also, i removed all your events from the HTML markup. We can do that in an unobtrusive way which will keep the markup clean and provides some seperation of concerns.

```
function addWPActivity() { 

   var r =$("<tr />").attr('data-wpid',wpid);

   r.append('<td><select class = "myPrgram form-control" id="SelectedWorkProgram' + wpid + '"><option>-Select -</option></select></td>');
   r.append('<td><select class ="form-control myActivity" id="SelectedActivity' + wpid + '" ><option>-Select-</option></select></td>');
   r.append('<td><input type="text" class="myAmt form-control" id="wpAmount' + wpid + '/></td>');        

   $("#wpTable").append(r);
   wpid++;
}
```

Now listens to the `change` event on the dropdown

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on("change",".myActivity",function(e){

     var _this=$(this);
     var wpid =_this.attr('data-wpid');
     var url = '@Url.Action("GetBudgetByWPAID", "Payments")',
     url = url +"?id="+wpid ;
     var amountTxt=_this.closest("tr").find("input.myAmt");
     $.post(url,function(result){
         //Set the value to the amount textbox.
      amountTxt.val(result);

     });

  });
  $(document).on("change",".myPrgram",function(e){

     alert('programchanged');
     var _this=$(this);
     var parentTr=_this.closest("tr");
     // You can do whatever you want here. 

  });

  $(document).on("change",".myAmt",function(e){

     alert('amount changed');
     var _this=$(this);
     var parentTr=_this.closest("tr");
     // You can do whatever you want here. 

  });
});
```